# Find largest possible value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If $$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=8$$ and $$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2+x_5^2=16,$$ where $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\in\Bbb R$.

What is the largest possible value of $x_5$?

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Two things. First, make sure you show us any work you have done on the problem, we'll be more inclined to help you if we know you've shown an effort. Second, please learn use of Mathjax to formulate questions and answers correctly. Link to Mathjax help here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Logic_Problem_42 correctly pointed out, $x_5$ is at it's greatest when all the other values are equal. Hence, let $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=y$ and the resulting equations you will get are:
$$4y^2+(x_5)^2=16$$
$$4y+x_5=8$$

We can rearrange the second into: $y=2-\frac{x_5}{4}$ and plug this into the first equation for:

$$4\bigg(2-\frac{x_5}{4}\bigg)^2+(x_5)^2=16$$
$$4\bigg(4+\frac{(x_5)^2}{16}-x_5\bigg)+(x_5)^2=16$$
$$16+\frac{(x_5)^2}{4}-4x_5+(x_5)^2=16$$
and solve from there.
You should get $x_5=0$ and $x_5=\frac{16}{5}$

Answer (score 2):

$x_5$ cannot be larger than $4$. Can it be $4$?

Hint: for a given $a$ the minimum of $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2$ under the condition $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=a$ is if $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4$.

Comment: X5 May be fraction also. Because it real number

Comment: @DietrichBurde if $x_5=4-\epsilon$, then via the first  statement $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=4+\epsilon$, and that throws out the second statement. So $x_5$ has to be a fair bit lower than 4.

Comment: (X1+x2+x3+x4+x5)<=x1^2+x2^2+x3^2+x4^2+x5^2 ........

Comment: (X1+x2+x3+x4+x5)^2<=x1^2+x2^2+x3^2+x4^2+x5^2 ........k

Comment: @user9640947, please use Mathjax, otherwise what you're saying is hard to understand. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Answer is 16/5.. .

Comment: Did you work that out or check the answers?

Comment: Please don't down vote if you don't know the solution of the question

Comment: then your question is $x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}+x_{5}=8$ and $x^2_{1}+x^2_{2}+x^2_{3}+x^2_{4}+x^2_{5}=16$ and answer $\displaystyle x_{5}\in\bigg[0,\frac{16}{5}\bigg]$

Comment: Yes I worked on that, I have Witten the condition for this question

Answer (score 2):

Using Inequality

$$\bigg(\frac{x^2_{1}+x^2_{2}+x^2_{3}+x^2_{4}}{4}\bigg)\geq \bigg(\frac{x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}}{4}\bigg)^2$$

$$\bigg(\frac{16-x^2_{5}}{4}\bigg)\geq \bigg(\frac{8-x_{5}}{4}\bigg)^2\Rightarrow x_{5}\in\bigg[0,\frac{16}{5}\bigg]$$

equality occus when $x_{1}=x_{2}=x_{3}=x_{4}$